# Can Angular JS load remote data without Ajax?

Tags: angularjs

Currently my company's page is built with Jquery but we are having some issues loading our client's page that contains bootstrap tabs due to the amount of information loaded at once.

One of the solutions is loading remote data with Ajax, but I would like to know if Angular JS has an alternative solution to that, because we are seriously considering rebuilding our entire page with Angular JS.

Comment: AngularJS itself uses Ajax for fetching dynamic contents from server when navigating within single page state.

Comment: in the short term it's not hard to load tabs on demand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularJS uses Ajax (read: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) for loading **dynamic** content from the **server**-side. There's no way to avoid this unless you load this information all through the frontend. For this case, it is probably a good decision to load the content asynchronously via AJAX. AngularJS will help with organization for your application.